# Multidimensional form array to JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, forms, underscore.js

I am working on a Backbone app that requires the input of rows of data (read: an array of objects).

I have the form set out like so:

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="items[][qty]"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="items[][job_number]"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="items[][description]"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="items[][purchase_order]"></td>
</tr>
[...]
```

with a dynamic number of rows.

I want to be able to retrieve the data in the form of:

```js
{
    items: [
        {
            qty: [val],
            job_number: [val],
            description: [val],
            purchase_order: [val]
        },
        [...]
    ]
}
```

The closest solution I have found is by [Aaron Shafovaloff](http://aaronshaf.wordpress.com/code/jquery-plugin-serialize-multi-dimensional-form-data-into-json/) but it doesn't support the arrays in the output (only objects). I could modify his code to do what I need but I figured I would ask here first since there is no point reinventing the wheel.

I am using jQuery and Underscore in my project so have access to their methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have mine this way to get multiple rows of text boxes:

```
    aItems = new Array();
    $("table tbody tr").each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);

        aItems.push({
            qty:$this.find('input[name="qty"]').val(),
            job_number: $this.find('input[name="job_number"]').val(),
            description:$this.find('input[name="description"]').val(),
            purchase_order:$this.find('input[name="purchase_order"]').val()
        });

    });
```

how about this:

```
    aItems = new Array();
    $("table tbody tr").each(function(){
        var items = {};

        $(this).find('input').each(function(){
            items[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
        }
        aItems.push(items);

    });
```

Comment: This is a good solution to this exact scenario but I was hoping for a solution that doesn't rely on the underlying markup (or need to know the field names prior) so I can keep my code DRY and re-use this method across multiple views.

Ideally something that could take the place of $("#formID").serialize()

Comment: How about not having definite input fields? But i have not actually tried the code..

Comment: That looks like it should work, and it is MUCH simple than the frankencode that I was trying to use. I'll test it out and accept if it does.

Answer (score 3):

Check https://github.com/serbanghita/formToObject

```
var myFormObj = new formToObject('myFormId');
// console.log(myFormObj);
```